# ROS 2 how have a callback and main code in same node / fille?

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I want to have a single file / node that will subscribe to a topic, while it will also let the node to run as a main code synchronously. The problem is that I can seem to find the proper way to have async and sync code in ROS2. I would like when the node is killed to send zero velocities to the robot to stop moving. For some reason, this doesn't work either.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import threading
import sys
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from rclpy.exceptions import ROSInterruptException
import signal


class RobotNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('my_node')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, '/camera/image_raw', self.callback, 10)

        self.publisher = self.create_publisher(Twist, '/cmd_vel', 10)
        self.rate = self.create_rate(10)

        self.robot_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
        self.robot_thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        desired_velocity = Twist()
        self.publisher.publish(desired_velocity)
        self.rate.sleep()

    def callback(self, data):
        image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, 'bgr8')
        cv2.namedWindow('Camera') 
        cv2.imshow('Camera', image)
        cv2.waitKey(3) 

    def main(self):
        while rclpy.ok():
            desired_velocity = Twist()
            desired_velocity.linear.x = 0.03
            try:
                for _ in range(10):
                    self.publisher.publish(desired_velocity)
                    self.rate.sleep()
            except Exception:
                pass


def main(args=None):
    def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        robot.stop()
        rclpy.shutdown()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    rclpy.init(args=args)
    robot = RobotNode()
    rclpy.spin(robot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `rclpy.init()` installs signal handlers for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` by default if no others are specified; as such your custom signal handler will not work as intended. If you're set on doing this this way you should instead specify what signal you want handled by your signal handler and which one you want handled by rclpy. i.e `rclpy.init(args=args, signal_handler_options=signal.SIGTERM)`

All of that said publishing 0 velocity isn't the best way to solve this problem, since nodes can go down for many reasons. I'd suggest your robot has a PID loop and some form of a timeout to bring velocity down.